# Symfony 4.4 - Returning a JSON Response of my user (getUser()) but I GET only NULL : security issue?

Tags: php, json, symfony

TLDR: When I want to return a JSON response with my User (->getUser()), accessible in GET (I test with Postman) I have only an empty JSON or NULL. While the same method works inside Symfony.

I am on a project based on Symfony 4.4 and ReactJS.
I created my User entity with the Security-bundle.

I made a controller to return a JSON response containing User's data.

```html
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Api;


use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

class UserConnectedController extends TypedController
{
    /**
     * @var Security
     */
    private Security $security;

    public function __construct(Security $security)
    {
        $this->security = $security;
    }
    /**
     * @Route("/api/user", name="user_connected", methods={"GET"})
     * @param Request $request
     * @return JsonResponse|Response
     */
    public function user(Request $request){
        $user = $this->security->getUser();

        return new JsonResponse($user);
        
    }

}
```

When I try to fetch this url with Postman (GET), I only have "NULL".
However, when I want to get this user inside Symfony (dumping it in a twig for example) it works perfectly.

Why is this $user accessible only in Symfony and not through a GET request ?
Is there any security-related issue ?

So far I've tried :

- different way of returning the JSON (new JsonResponse, $this->json, homemade function that is working to fetch others DB informations like a list of categories for example) : I always get NULL or am empty JSON.
- I moved this method into different controllers, such as securitycontroller.php, its the same.
- I modified the security.yaml firewall as written in the docs (https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/json_login_setup.html)

None of these worked.
If you have any hint, it will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `new JsonResponse` you encode your object with json_encode function. In this case, you will get the empty JSON object. `$this->json` it is a wrapper on `new JsonResponse`, which firstly looking for the serializer in your container. So you have at least two options

- Install Symfony or JMS serializer, it will simplify your life
- Use JsonSerializable interface and manually define needed fields, not the best variant

Comment: Ok. I actually dont understand properly the serializer, but my boss made me a custom serializer. If I use it, it is the same. My json is empty. Someone is telling me that Postman wont be able to reach my connected user because he is not part of the session. I get it even less. Thank you for  your help.

Comment: Paste dump($user); into your controller, with that, you will see if your $user is not empty.

Comment: I did it at the beginning and I had a $user. The problem is cookie_session related.
When I authenticate in localhost:8000 (Symfony) I have a related cookie, but when I fetch the concerned url in localhost:8000 with React (localhost:3000) or Postman, I dont have this cookie. I solved it by authorizing cross-origin request between my 2 local hosts.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was indeed security related and specifically from the credentials.

I should have shared the credentials in the request.

```html
fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/user", {
  credentials: 'include'
})
```

Then only CORS will block the request and with a symfony bundle (nelmio) I allowed to share credentials from cross-origin and bingo its working !